# GSPREAD sometimes works, sometimes not work (module 'gspread' has no attribute 'service_account')

Tags: python, gspread

I try to connect google sheets. Yesterday it worked, today it doesn't work. The error message is  `module 'gspread' has no attribute 'service account'` I tried `pip install - import gspread - all`, but the module doesn't work. The python code is the same as yesterday.

How can I make Gspread work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: good day. Yesterday i tried to start code from another session of Google Colab (another PC), and it works...! I saw topic with the same problem with gspread and there is no any answer ... i think problem in Google colab sessions...